# Gsuite Accounts Got Suspended by reseller after reseller company is down

Tags: email, google-workspace

I had ordered some gsuite email accounts through one of local reseller of gsuite, the payment was made for one year, it is about six months that i am using these accounts by about one month ago the reseller company got down and was out of reach now the have suspended our gsuite email accounts, while there are very important data of our organization in those emails and are used as our contact with lots of people. is there any way to get back control of these accounts? one of our accounts was admin and others were normal. I have tried google domain but it is not available in our country.

Thank you from your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you own that information you can contact G Suite Support to detach your account from the reseller, even they are down Google does not do anything on their end to affect your account but if you paid 1 year you should be able to keep your account active. Check this link https://support.google.com/work/reseller/answer/6182419?hl=en it provides information about how to transfer a customer to Google directly, sorry for the late response but I just found it. I hope this helps, greetings.

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue is resolved now, yeah I did the same as you said.